# C++ mixing strongly typed base class with CRTP and return value type deduction

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++14, crtp

I have some conceptual problem in a class hierarchy, where the Base class depends on a fixed scalar type `T`, but the derived CRTP'ed classes use return value type deduction.

For example, consider the following class hierarchy:

```
template<typename ... Args> struct VectorBase;

template<typename T>
struct VectorBase<T>
{
     virtual T eval(int) const = 0;
     auto operator[](int i) {return this->eval(i);}
};

template<typename T, typename Derived>
struct VectorBase<T, Derived> : public VectorBase<T>
{
     virtual T eval(int i) const override final { return this->operator[](i); }
     auto operator[](int i) const
     {
          return static_cast<Derived const&>(*this).operator[](i);
     }
};

template<typename T>
struct Vector : public VectorBase<T, Vector<T> >
{
     //just for code shortness,
     //in reality there is a container which returns the corresponding elements
     auto operator[](int i) const { return T{}; }
};

template<typename VectorType>
struct SomeTransformation : public VectorBase< /* ... what to write here generically? */ double, SomeTransformation<VectorType> >
{
     VectorType const& v;
     SomeTransformation(VectorType const& _v) : v(_v) {}
     auto operator[](int i) const
     {
          //do something with vector v and return i-th element, e.g.
          return v[i]*0.1;
     }
};
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0647408d50a5aa7d)

Now, given a specific vector with value type `int`, say, one can apply `SomeTransformation` and get a vector of value type `double`. Moreover, I can be sure that `SomeTransformation` derives from `VectorBase<double>`, so that, for example, I can't falsely assign it to a `VectorBase<int>`-pointer:

```
int main()
{
    Vector<int> v;
    std::cout<<typeid(decltype(v[0])).name()<<std::endl;  //prints "i" for int        

    auto u = SomeTransformation<decltype(v)>(v);
    std::cout<<typeid(decltype(u[0])).name()<<std::endl;  //prints "d" for double        

    //works
    std::unique_ptr<VectorBase<double> > ud = std::make_unique<SomeTransformation<decltype(v)> >(v);

    //gives a compile-time error, which is good
    //std::unique_ptr<VectorBase<int> > ui = std::make_unique<SomeTransformation<decltype(v)> >(v);     
}
```

Now for the problem: in the scalar type argument of `SomeTransformation`, where I wrote `/* ... what to write here generically? */`, I really would want to write something like

```
template<typename VectorType>
struct SomeTransformation : 
  public VectorBase<decltype(std::declval<SomeTransformation<VectorType> >().operator[](0)), SomeTransformation<VectorType> >
{
     //...
};
```

in order to deduce the value type of the transformation automatically and propagate this type down to the base class. However, this doesn't seem to work, which I think is because the base classes are instantiated before the derived class ... so the class of which I want to deduce the type doesn't exists yet.

**Is there any way to obtain this behaviour *without breaking the inheritance hierarchy*?**

Comment: Do you have to use an inheritance hierarchy direcly for `SomeTransformation`? Why not write `SomeTransformation` independently (fulfilling a concept), and provide an adapter class template that inherits from `VectorBase<..>`?

Comment: @dyp: yes, that would work and I also had this once, before I realized that in my case it is rather convenient to keep the inheritance relationship ... otherwise I would have to re-implement several functions (like `size(), update(...)` etc.) and also to re-declare some members in the concept classes.

Comment: @dyp: I posted an answer with some alternative that still has some issues, have a look if you want, thnx in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand your concerns. Could you provide an example? Could you split the base class into an interface (with only pure virtual functions) and a base class (with whatever convenience functions and members you want to use in the derived class)?

Comment: @dyp: I'm not sure I made them clear: my goal is to use the deduced return type as template parameter in the base class, while keeping the inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: I understand your issue with the current design. What I don't understand is why you need that design: Why do you need to derive from a base class that contains a virtual function, instead of isolating that virtual function in an unrelated class and adapting your implementation to that interface?

Comment: @dyp: that's a valid question, and I also had it like this. I switched to the above alternative because the concept classes require a lot of the stuff that's contained in the base classes (which I don't want to pass every time).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a possible alternative by myself and want to bring it up for discussion.

One could for instance add a type parameter `T` also to the derived class and then use a dummy type in order to instantiate this class once. With this, it is possible to deduce the return type of the so-created class, which is used in a next step to instantiate the class to be really used.

Example:

```
namespace detail
{
    template<typename T, typename VectorType>
    struct SomeTransformation : 
      public VectorBase<T, SomeTransformation<T, VectorType> >
    {
        //the same as above
    };
}

struct DummyType
{
     //make any type convertible to DummyType
     template<typename T> DummyType(T const&) {}
};

template<typename VectorType>
using SomeTransformationValueType =
  decltype(std::declval<detail::SomeTransformation<DummyType, VectorType> >().operator[](0));

template<typename VectorType>
using SomeTransformation = 
   typename detail::SomeTransformation<SomeTransformationValueType<VectorType>, VectorType>;
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/41e527db66ba8d39)